# C# - Replace string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

```
string text = @"<xml>
        <trans>2804</trans>
        <saletype>Quick-Service</saletype>
        <listitem>
        <item><type>1</type><qty>1</qty><desc>Description1 1 Printed Description1><1,16,1,5160,0,0,0,0,5160,52000</desc><cost> 52,000</cost></item>
        <item><type>1</type><qty>2</qty><desc>Description2 2 Printed Description2><1,16,1,5161,0,0,0,0,5161,52000</desc><cost> 52,000</cost></item>
        </listitem>
        </xml>";
string result = @"<xml>
        <trans>2804</trans>
        <saletype>Quick-Service</saletype>
        <listitem>
        <item><type>1</type><qty>1</qty><desc>Description1 Printed Description1</desc><cost> 52,000</cost></item>
        <item><type>1</type><qty>2</qty><desc>Description2 Printed Description2</desc><cost> 52,000</cost></item>
        </listitem>
        </xml>";
```

As the above request I want to delete a string in the desc tag. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why regex?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174402/replacing-the-innertext-of-an-xml-node-element does this helps?

Comment: you haven't really defined what you are trying to do too well.  Also when dealing with XML, it's far better to parse it with .nets xml libs

Comment: As mentioned before, regex isn't the best but if you insist you could try '(<desc>\w+ )\d+ ([^<]+)<[0-9,]+' => $1$2

Comment: This string has been fixed irreplaceable. Problem I need to get Description, Printed Description in desc tag

Comment: @Furmek I need you more specific guidance. Can you help me?

Comment: @Furmek I have found the answer from you. Thanks for your help. Many thank.